# Garbage from first read of BufferedReader stream

Tags: java, telnet

I am building a simple telnet connection daemon for communications between internal network applications, and I ran into an issue when reading the first line from BufferedReader.

This code snippet is not complete due to the fact there is a lot of other junk in there so I have stripped it down only to include the object creation and read from the steam.

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.client.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(this.client.getOutputStream(), true);
String line;

while (true) {
    out.println(flag); // flag is just an integer               
    System.out.println(line);
    // Processing the line and updating 'flag' accordingly
}
```

Entering `test` into the telnet connection yielded  `v? v  v? v' ²? v? ²?test` in the console that was running the program. This does not happen to lines sent after the first one.

Is there a way to clear that garbage out before the user interfaces with it so it doesn't get sent with the first line? or is this issue caused by my telnet client (and might be fixed when I write a client that interfaces with this)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect it's the telnet protocol negotiation. Ideally, you should handle it having read [RFC 854](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc854.html) carefully.

Note that you *shouldn't* just use `InputStreamReader` without specifying the character encoding - it's very unlikely that the platform default encoding is the one you want.

Comment: I think you're right, I should have been using raw, not telnet as I am not utilizing anything from that protocol (in fact, I am not sure why I called it telnet). Anyway I figured it out, thanks.

Comment: @SamT: `telnet` is often used as a "plain TCP/IP connection client", while it is *actually* a client for the very specific telnet protocol (that's hardly really used these days).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer I wouldn't say it's 'hardly really used'. You would be surprised at the amount of code out there that talks e.g. TN3270 to banking backends. I have a system with an embedded Telnet client/server in production at the moment.

Comment: @EJP: ok, that might be right. But I still think that the amount of "telnet abuse" is bigger than the use of `telnet` as an actual telnet client.